# How to fix the server not fetching results from api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, momentjs

I am using the api called Cliniko for booking appointment between doctor and patient. For some reason it's not fetching the unavailable blocks on mobile anymore. It works fine on computer just not on mobile.

It started happening after i implemented some filters on the api results. I make request like this

```
  
let date = moment('2020-12-22', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z').utc().format()

  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `https://api.ca1.cliniko.com/v1/unavailable_blocks?q[]=created_at:>=${date}`,
    headers: {headers},
    data: data
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      return res.status(200).json({ error: false, data: response.data })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: true, error })
    });
})
```

Before i didn't have that date filter in the url. i used to have it like this

`url: 'https://api.ca1.cliniko.com/v1/unavailable_blocks'`

After i added that filter it stopped working on mobile but works on a computer.

Comment: That API uses http authentication. Did the mobile browser ask for that? Did you enter the login details correctly?

Comment: the browser didn't ask for any authentication.

Comment: So I guess you put them in `headers`? Anyway, try debugging the mobile browser. Chrome has a remote debugging feature; if you connect the phone to your computer, you should be able to check the mobile Chrome's console. Also, the code in your question doesn't do anything with the API result?

Comment: Yeah i put those in the headers. It does fetch the api results out. Even if i open that api endpoint on mobile it has that JSON data but its not updating that in my front end on a phone when it works fine on a computer.